# Image/Video Size in Bytes selected from image picker

Tags: iphone, upload, uiimagepickercontroller, filesize

In my app i have to upload image or video which is below 10 MB size to the server. So i need to check the size of the image or video selected from image picker controller before uploading it to the server. i have been searching for the answer since 2 days. can anybody help me in this regard, thanks in advance. I have written like

```
        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString* fullPathToFile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
             NSLog(@"fullPathToFile:%@", fullPathToFile);
             NSError *error = nil;
             NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPathToFile error:&error];

             if (!error) 
             {
                 NSNumber *size = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
                 NSLog(@"File size: %@", size);
             }
```

but it returning null.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got my problem solved. For that 1st we have to convert that image/video into NSData and then we are having the property like "length".
For eg:

```
  fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
  //fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
  NSUInteger fileLength = [fileData length];
  NSLog(@"fileLength:%u",fileLength);
```

it returns size in Bytes. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` and from the returned dictionary access the size using the key `filesize`.